# Error installing ZeroMQ

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from zmq import core, devices
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/core/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from zmq.core import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/core/socket.so: undefined symbol: 
zmq_sendmsg
```

I am getting above error. I have followed steps given on the official site of ZeroMQ.

Comment: Have you ensured that source code is for the same versoin of ZeroMQ? ZeroMQ-2.x and 3.x have some differences in names of functions etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a similar issue when building for Java, `UnsatisifedLinkError`, after the `so` libraries were copied to `/usr/local/lib`, seems like your issue might be the same...I fixed it by logging off then logging back in again, I read something about the libraries not being visible until the user logs back in, weird, but it worked for me.