# Java Path zeromq setting

Tags: java, macos, unix, zeromq, apache-storm

I am using MAC OSX

I already follow the instruction on 0mq official site to install

when i compile it , i dont get any error.

But when i run the following command

```
java -classpath /Users/john/jzmq/ -cp $(lein classpath) storm.starter.WordCountTopology
```

I got the following error.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jzmq in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1878)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1087)
at org.zeromq.ZMQ.<clinit>(ZMQ.java:34)
at storm.starter.spout.RandomSentenceSpout.nextTuple(RandomSentenceSpout.java:39)
at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__3985$fn__3997$fn__4026.invoke(executor.clj:502)
at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__465.invoke(util.clj:377)
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

My setting
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home

I also have zmq.jar under 
/usr/local/lib   and

/usr/local/share/java

I read through all the google search I can found. Still no crew why my one is not working

Comment: how can you solved it , please i'm facing same problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to setting the JAR classpath, you need to specify where the jzmq `.so` library files reside. Did you build zmq, libzmq, and jzmq exactly as described in the directions? If so, you should see the `.so` library files in `/usr/local/lib` and `zmq.jar` in `/usr/local/share/java`, confirm that, then logout/login based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16522807/791406), then try this:

```
java -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib -cp  "/usr/local/share/java/zmq.jar:/Users/john/jzmq/<your jar here>" storm.starteer.WordCountTopology
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I downloaded the code, did cd jzmq-jni, config, and make install but it put .dylib and .a files in my /usr/local/lib - not .so files.